# How would I add another column and populate it?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables

I know this is way out of left field, but i was wanting to see if anyone could help.

I am wanting to add a column, populating the data from a certain variable (the variable i have yet to discover the name of). This is a plugin for wordpress and the developer wont really help.

Last ditch effort i guess. Here is the code:

```
 }$output.='><tr><th>' . __('Request For', 'wpsc-support-tickets') . '</th><th>'
 . __('Status', 'wpsc-support-tickets') . '</th><th>' 
 . __('Last Reply', 'wpsc-support-tickets') 
 . '</th><th>' . __('Department', 'wpsc-support-tickets') . '</th></tr>';
```

I added the last column, "Department".

Now, looking at the following code, i cant figure out how to populate that data (assuming i knew the variable even)

```
 $output .= '<tr><td>
 <a href="" onclick="loadTicket(' . $result['primkey'] . ',\'' . $canReopen . '\');
 return false;" ';

if ($result['resolution'] == strtolower('open') ) {
    $resresolution = __('Open', 'wpsc-support-tickets');
} elseif ($result['resolution'] == strtolower('closed') ) {
    $resresolution = __('Closed', 'wpsc-support-tickets');
} else {
    $resresolution = $result['resolution'];
}

if ($devOptions['disable_inline_styles'] == 'false') {
    $output.='style="border:none;text-decoration:none;"';
}$output.='><img';
if ($devOptions['disable_inline_styles'] == 'false') {
    $output.=' style="float:left;border:none;margin-right:5px;"';
}$output.=' src="' . plugins_url('/images/page_edit.png', __FILE__) . '"
alt="' . __('View', 'wpsc-support-tickets') . '"  /> ' . base64_decode($result['title']) . 
'</a></td><td>' . $resresolution . '</td><td>' 
 . date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), 
 $result['last_updated']) . ' ' . __('by', 'wpsc-support-tickets') . '
 ' . $last_staff_reply .    '</td>
</tr>';
```

again - where might i add the variable for the column "department" if the variable were $department_var?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to the very end of that large chunk of mess before the closing `</tr>`...

change

```
...$last_staff_reply . '</td></tr>';
```

to

```
...$last_staff_reply . '</td><td>' . $department_var . '</td></tr>';
```